# program crashes while inserting second node in Binary search tree

Tags: c, pointers, struct, binary-tree

Here i wrote a code to implement binary search tree.it doesn't give any error while inserting root node.But whenever i try to insert child node i get the following warnings

> passing argument 1 of push incompatible pointer type
>
> expected struct node ** but argument is of struct node *
>
> passing argument 1 of push incompatible pointer type

and then the program crashes.What might go wrong with this code ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct node {

    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};
void insert(int value);
void push(struct node **root_node,struct node *newNode);
void search(struct node *root_node,int value);

struct node *root;
int main(){
    root= NULL;
    int option,value;
    for(;;){
       printf("Please select an option from below : \n");
       printf("1 for insert\n");
       printf("2 for search\n");
       printf("please enter your option : ");
       scanf("%d",&option);
       printf("\n");
       switch(option){
           case 1:
               printf("you choose to insert\n");
               printf("input your value :");
               scanf("%d",&value);
               insert(value);
               printf("\n");
               break;

           default:
               break;

       }
    }
}

void insert(int value){
    struct node newNode ;

    newNode.data = value;
    newNode.left = NULL;
    newNode.right = NULL;


    push(&root,&newNode);

}
void push(struct node **root_node,struct node *newNode){

  if(*root_node==NULL){
         *root_node = newNode;
         printf("inserted\n\n\n");
    }else{
         if((*root_node)->data > newNode->data){
              push((*root_node)->left,newNode);
              printf("left\n");
         }else{
            push((*root_node)->right,newNode);
            printf("right\n");
         }

    }

}
```

Comment: 1) `struct node newNode ;` : lifetime of `newNode` is in local scope. 2) `push((*root_node)->left,newNode);` --> `push(&(*root_node)->left, newNode);`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this type of line:

```
push((*root_node)->left,newNode);
```

`(*root_node)->left` is a `struct node*` but your function expects `struct node**` (double pointer). So you need a change like:

```
push(&((*root_node)->left),newNode);
     ^
     Notice
```

Besides that, you can't put local variables in the tree as you do here:

```
void insert(int value){
    struct node newNode ;  // Local variable
```

Use `malloc` instead

```
void insert(int value){
    struct node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Comment: why i can't put local variable in tree..i am using pointer to point to it..can you please explain

Comment: The local variable is lost (aka out of scope) when the function returns so your pointer will point to some "invalid" memory, i.e. memory that doesn't hold the local variable anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node* search(struct node* root, int key)
{
    // Base Cases: root is null or key is present at root
    if (root == NULL || root->key == key)
       return root;

    // Key is greater than root's key
    if (root->key < key)
       return search(root->right, key);

    // Key is smaller than root's key
    return search(root->left, key);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is nice code, but it's not really germane to the question which is about why the `insert()` operation fails.